# Emulator Error: Android.Database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: 'Index 0 requested, with a size of 0'

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to devlop an ocr app it picks an image from gallery and do the Ocr my code works fine for the real device but with the emulator when pick an image from gallery it throw an Android.Database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException.Please help me to solve my emulator error thanks in advance.

```
Activity.cs

    public string GetPathToImage(Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        string doc_id = "";
        using (var c1 = ContentResolver.Query(uri, null, null, null, null))
        {
            c1.MoveToFirst();
            string document_id = c1.GetString(0);
            doc_id = document_id.Substring(document_id.LastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        }

        string path = null;

        // The projection contains the columns we want to return in our query.
        string selection = Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id + " =? ";
        using (var cursor = ContentResolver.Query(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, null, selection, new string[] { doc_id }, null))
        {
              if (cursor == null) return path;
              var columnIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data);
               cursor.MoveToFirst();
               path = cursor.GetString(columnIndex);

        }
        return path;
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.GalleryPage);
        // Create your application here

        txtView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtView);
        _imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

        button.Click += delegate
        {
            Intent = new Intent();
            Intent.SetType("image/*");
            Intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
            StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(Intent, "Select Picture"), PickImageId);
        }; 
    }
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if ((requestCode == PickImageId) && (resultCode == Result.Ok) && (data != null))
        {
            Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;
            var path = GetPathToImage(uri);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Image path == " + path);
           //  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(path);
            Bitmap bitmap =  loadAndResizeBitmap.Coversionandresize(path,4032,3024);
            ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
            matrix.SetSaturation(0);
           _imageView.SetColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix));
           _imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);

            TextRecognizer txtRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(ApplicationContext).Build();
            if (!txtRecognizer.IsOperational)
            {
                Log.Error("Error", "Detector dependencies are not yet available");
            }
            else
            {
                Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().SetBitmap(bitmap).Build();
                SparseArray items = txtRecognizer.Detect(frame);
                StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < items.Size(); i++)
                {
                    TextBlock item = (TextBlock)items.ValueAt(i);
                    strBuilder.Append(item.Value);
                    strBuilder.Append("/n");
                  //  strBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                }
                txtView.Text = strBuilder.ToString();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

}

Android.Database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: 'Index 0 requested, with a size of 0'

Comment: which line of code does this happen on?

Comment: path = cursor.GetString(columnIndex);

Comment: Does cursor have anything in it?

Comment: when i selected image in my device it is taking path but in emulator it is showing null

Comment: Umm i am not sure what are you talking about

Comment: could you please explain your question one more time

Answer (score 1):

One of my apps used this feature, you can try the following code:

IOUtil.cs

```
public class IOUtil
{
  public static string getPath(Context context, Android.Net.Uri uri)
   {
    bool isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.IsDocumentUri(context, uri))
    {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri))
        {
            var docId = DocumentsContract.GetDocumentId(uri);
            string[] split = docId.Split(':');
            var type = split[0];

            if ("primary".Equals(type, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri))
        {

            string id = DocumentsContract.GetDocumentId(uri);
            Android.Net.Uri contentUri = ContentUris.WithAppendedId(
                    Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), long.Parse(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri))
        {
            var docId = DocumentsContract.GetDocumentId(uri);
            string[] split = docId.Split(':');
            var type = split[0];

            Android.Net.Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".Equals(type))
            {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri;
            }
            else if ("video".Equals(type))
            {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.ExternalContentUri;
            }
            else if ("audio".Equals(type))
            {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ExternalContentUri;
            }

            var selection = "_id=?";
            var selectionArgs = new string[] {
                split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".Equals(uri.Scheme, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".Equals(uri.Scheme, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        return uri.Path;
    }

    return null;
}

public static string getDataColumn(Context context, Android.Net.Uri uri, string selection,
string[] selectionArgs)
{

    ICursor cursor = null;
    var column = "_data";
    string[] projection = {
        column
    };

    try
    {
        cursor = context.ContentResolver.Query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.MoveToFirst())
        {
            int column_index = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.GetString(column_index);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.Close();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static bool isExternalStorageDocument(Android.Net.Uri uri)
{
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".Equals(uri.Authority);
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static bool isDownloadsDocument(Android.Net.Uri uri)
{
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".Equals(uri.Authority);
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static bool isMediaDocument(Android.Net.Uri uri)
{
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".Equals(uri.Authority);
}

public static byte[] readFile(string file)
{
    try
    {
        return readFile(new File(file));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex);
        return new byte[0];
    }
}

public static byte[] readFile(File file)
{
    // Open file
    var f = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");

    try
    {
        // Get and check length
        long longlength = f.Length();
        var length = (int)longlength;

        if (length != longlength)
            throw new IOException("Filesize exceeds allowed size");
        // Read file and return data
        byte[] data = new byte[length];
        f.ReadFully(data);
        return data;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex);
        return new byte[0];
    }
    finally
    {
        f.Close();
    }
 }
 }
```

For more details, you can check: 
[how ca in get data from choosed file with Intent.CreateChooser(Intent, "Select Any File") as byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56589454/how-ca-in-get-data-from-choosed-file-with-intent-createchooserintent-select-a/56594624#56594624)

Comment: @kiran kumar Hi, if the answer is useful for you, could you mark it as a answer ? :)